# Visual Studio "Syntax Error." with no line in an MVC3 Partial View

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

When I open two very small MVC 3 partial view file (*.vbhtml) in Visual Studio 2010 Express SP1, I get a "Syntax Error." with no Line or Column defined. Visual Studio does not tell me what's wrong with these partial view.

**[Screenshot](https://www.Scolab.com/Public/Jing/CM/Visual-Studio-2011-12-02_2214.png)**

Anybody knows how I can debug this? I cleaned and rebuilt the project. I restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Either change `@<option...` to `@:<option...`, `<text><option...</text>` or remove the @.  Razor should be able to figure out that this is text.

Comment: Solution 1 (@:) fails with "Syntax errors". Solution 2 (<text>) and 3 (remove the @) fails with two new errors "Keyword is not valid as an identifier" and "Identifier expected."

Answer (score 0):

Why not use available html helpers to generate the dropdown list:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of CarlText2.Tag)
@Html.DropDownList(
    "tag",
    New SelectList(Model.Select(Function(x) New With {.TagID = x.TagID, .Text = x.TagID + " " + x.Text}), "TagID", "Text"),
    New With {.id = "doc-selected-titletag"})
```

and by the way you should be using a view model in which you will directly have a property Text containing the preformated text you want to show in each option.

Comment: This is great, but I still have the syntax error with no line or column.